# parse a tab delimited data using perl

Tags: perl

I have a tab delimited data. I want to process that data using perl. I am a newbie to perl and could not figure out how to solve .

This is sample table: My original file is almost a GB

```
gi|306963568|gb|GL429799.1|_1316857_1453052 13  1
gi|306963568|gb|GL429799.1|_1316857_1453052 14  1
gi|306963568|gb|GL429799.1|_1316857_1453052 15  1
gi|306963568|gb|GL429799.1|_1316857_1453052 16  1
gi|306963568|gb|GL429799.1|_1316857_1453052 17  1
gi|306963568|gb|GL429799.1|_1316857_1453052 360 1
gi|306963568|gb|GL429799.1|_1316857_1453052 361 1
gi|306963568|gb|GL429799.1|_1316857_1453052 362 1
gi|306963568|gb|GL429799.1|_1316857_1453052 363 1
gi|306963568|gb|GL429799.1|_1316857_1453052 364 1
gi|306963568|gb|GL429799.1|_1316857_1453052 365 1
gi|306963568|gb|GL429799.1|_1316857_1453052 366 1
gi|306963580|gb|GL429787.1|_4276355_4500645 38640   1
gi|306963580|gb|GL429787.1|_4276355_4500645 38641   1
gi|306963580|gb|GL429787.1|_4276355_4500645 38642   1
gi|306963580|gb|GL429787.1|_4276355_4500645 38643   1
gi|306963580|gb|GL429787.1|_4276355_4500645 38644   1
gi|306963580|gb|GL429787.1|_4276355_4500645 38645   1
```

I would like to get the output as 
Name, start value, end value, average

```
gi|306963568|gb|GL429799.1|_1316857_1453052 13  17  1   
gi|306963568|gb|GL429799.1|_1316857_1453052 360 366 1   
gi|306963580|gb|GL429787.1|_4276355_4500645 38640   38645   1
```

it will be great if someone could share their wisdom.

Comment: Use [`Text::CSV_XS`](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Text-CSV_XS/). CSV is a horrible nasty format that hates all of humanity, always keep a well tested parsing library between you and CSV.

Comment: @muistooshort: Tab-delimited files are different from CSV and are almost always well-behaved as there is no attempt to quote fields containing the separator character: a tab character is simply invalid in the data.

Comment: @Borodin: Irrelevant. Even though it's _called_ Text::CSV/CSV_XS, it will work with tab or pipe separators. Just pass a `sep_char` parameter to the constructor.

Comment: That is tab delimited, not tab separated.

Comment: @DaveSherohman: You're missing the point. Yes, sure, `Text::CSV` and family will do their best at parsing a tab-delimited file (although you will also have to disable `sep_char` and `escape_char`). But there is little point as all that is necessary is `split /\t/`, and that is what the module would do if it got it right. The tab-delimited MIME type prohibits data that contains tab characters, and that is exactly how everyone uses it. Comma-separated values are different, with quote characters to delimit fields that contain commas, and an escape character to protect embedded quote characters.

Comment: Is the data in the file always sorted?

Comment: @tchrist: AFAIK tab-delimited and tab-separated aren't recognised as distinct data types.

Comment: @Borodin Delimited and separated are always different things, and this makes a difference in the parse and handling. Just because some people use the wrong word doesn’t mean that they are the same. Delimited means surrounded by; quoted strings are quote-delimited. If you have something like “:a:b:c:” it is 3 fields when colon-delimited, 5 fields when colon-separated, and 4 fields when colon-terminated. See why it is important to use the right word? It cannot be programmed correctly otherwise.

Comment: @tchrist: a data format is defined by its definition, not by its name. Whatever you call it, a format is ambiguous until it's defined. Delimited doesn't mean "surrounded by" it means "has a limit marked". Common CSV files are quote-, comma-, *and* newline-delimited, and calling them comma-separated doesn't tell you how to process them. There is an ambiguity in `:a:b:c:` that isn't resolved by calling it colon-delimited or colon-separated. It is likely to be both, and we don't know that it isn't mal-formed. CSV and tab-separated/delimited are *genres* of data format, not specifications.

Comment: Option autosplit : -a

Answer (score 1):

The general pattern is

```
use strict;
use warnings;

open my $fh, '<', 'myfile' or die $!;
while (<$fh>) {
  chomp;
  my @fields = split /\t/;
  ...
}
```

Within the loop the fields can be accessed as `$fields[0]` through `$fields[2]`.

---

**Update**

I have understood your question better, and I think this solution will work for you. *Note that it assumes the input data is sorted, as you have shown in your question.*

It accumulates the start and end values, the total and the count in hash `%data`, and keeps a list of all the names encountered in `@names` so that the data can be displayed in the order it was read.

The program expects the input file name as a parameter on the command line.

You need to consider the formatting of the average because it is a floating point value. As it stands it will display the value to sixteen significant figures, and you may want to curtail that using `sprintf`.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my ($filename) = @ARGV;
open my $fh, '<', $filename or die qq{Unable to open "$filename": $!};

my @names;
my %data;
my $current_name = '';
my $last_index;

while (<$fh>) {
  chomp;
  my ($name, $index, $value) = split /\t/;

  if ( $current_name ne $name or $index > $last_index + 1 ) {
    push @names, $name unless $data{$name};
    push @{ $data{$name} }, {
      start => $index,
      count => 0,
      total => 0,
    };
    $current_name = $name;
  }

  my $entry = $data{$name}[-1];
  $entry->{end} = $index;
  $entry->{count} += 1;
  $entry->{total} += $value;
  $last_index = $index;
}

for my $name (@names) {
  for my $entry (@{ $data{$name} }) {
    my ($start, $end, $total, $count) = @{$entry}{qw/ start end total count /};
    print join("\t", $name, $start, $end, $total / $count), "\n";
  }
}
```

**output**

```
gi|306963568|gb|GL429799.1|_1316857_1453052 13  17  1
gi|306963568|gb|GL429799.1|_1316857_1453052 360 366 1
gi|306963580|gb|GL429787.1|_4276355_4500645 38640 38645 1
```

Answer (score 0):

This will produce the same output for the sample in your question:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl -n
#
my ($name, $i, $value) = split(/\t/);

sub print_stats {
    print join("\t", $prev_name, $start, $prev_i, $sum / ($prev_i - $start + 1)), "\n";
}

if ($prev_name eq $name && $i == $prev_i + 1) {
    $sum += $value;
    $prev_i = $i;
}
else {
    if ($prev_name) {
        &print_stats();
    }
    $start = $i;
    $prev_name = $name;
    $sum = $value;
    $prev_i = $i;
}
END {
    &print_stats();
}
```

Use it as:

```
./parser.pl < sample.txt
```

**UPDATE:** answers to the questions in comments:

- To print output to a file, run like this: `./parser.pl < sample.txt > output.txt`
- `$prev_name` and `$prev_i` are NOT initialized, so they are `undef` at first (= NULL)

Comment: Hi,Thank you os much. It works perfectly.  I would like to know how print output to a file. I would like to know how you initialize the "$prev_name" and "$prev_i" variables, and how do you read through the lines. I know it can be done using while (defined()).I also would like to know why you have to use $prev_name twice. "if ($prev_name && $prev_name".

Comment: I updated my post to answer your questions. The `$prev_name && ...` means in human language that "`$prev_name` is not null AND ...`. After some thinking I realized the condition was redundant, so I removed it from the post, see the updated version.

Answer (score -1):

You could do something like this....

```
open (FILE, 'data.txt');
while (<FILE>) {
chomp;
($name, $start_value, $end_value, $average) = split("\t");
print "Name: $name\n";
print "Start Value: $start_value\n";
print "End Value: $End_Value\n";
print "Average: %average
print "---------\n";
}
close (FILE);
exit;
```

Those look like GenBank files...so I'm unsure where you are getting the start, end values, average.

Comment: For a very long time now best practice has been to use lexical file handles and the three-parameter `open`. It has never been a good idea to open a file without checking whether it succeeded and printing `$!` in a `die` string if not. Also code without `use strict` is a very bad idea.

Answer (score -1):

Here's an example using [Text::CSV](https://metacpan.org/module/Text%3a%3aCSV):

```
use Text::CSV;  # This will implicitly use Text::CSV_XS if it's installed

my $parser = Text::CSV->new( { sep_char => '|' } );
open my $fh, '<', 'myfile' or die $!;

while (my $row = $parser->getline($fh)) {
  # $row references an array of field values from the line just read
}
```

Also, as a minor side detail, your sample data is delimited by pipe characters, not tabs, although that may just be to avoid copy/paste errors for those answering your question.  If the actual data is tab-delimited, set `sep_char` to `"\t"` instead of `'|'`.

Comment: The OP's data *is* tab-delimited. There are three fields per line, and the first, that he calls `Name`, contains multiple pipes.

Comment: OK, in that case, as my answer states: "If the actual data is tab-delimited, set sep_char to `"\t"` instead of `'|'`." The sample data as posted does not contain tabs.

Comment: Yes, it does contain tab characters. If you copied the rendered HTML then of course you won't see them. You need to edit the question and copy from the edit box.